# JavaScript to add id to ul tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add an ID namely "myMenu" (using JavaScript) to a ul for a search filter unfortunately i cant get to ul tag to change it but wanted to JavaScript it in. Im new to JavaScript and wanted to specify from class to ul.

```
<div class="main-menu">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

<input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
```

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's little point adding an `id` attribute to an element at runtime. If you can find the element to add the `id` to it, then that implies you already have a way of targeting the element to get a reference to it without the need for the id.

Comment: The ul is in a template which i cant get to but wanted to add the ID in only for a particular page.

Comment: `ul.setAttribute('id', 'your-id')` refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) or to be simple as `ul.id = 'your-id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add an id to the `ul` shown in your sample, just do that:

```
$("div.main-menu ul").attr("id", "myMenu");
```

as @Rory-MacCrossan says, have you need of id?

Comment: Thanks @frenchy maybe not adding the id but to target that specific ul in the JavaScript. Would help if i added the input bar as well in the example...

Comment: @Lan.m so $("div.main-menu ul")  does the job...except if you have more div with same class, you could precise the selector with .first() or .eq(numberpos)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me but thank you @frenchy

Comment: i dont see why?  its the right syntax, or your html is not again loaded? you could know that if you do a **console.log($("div.main-menu ul").length);**   if the value is 0, the div is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with vanilla JavaScript like this:

```js
const ulEl = document.querySelector('.main-menu > ul');
ulEl.setAttribute('id', 'main-menu-list');

console.dir(ulEl);
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also it seems to me it might be more appropriate to make `<div class='main-menu'>` to `<div id='main-menu'>` - unless you plan on giving additional elements the `main-menu` class for some reason?

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute